# Checking for skewness in data

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-cleaning, visualization, seaborn

I have a data frame consisting of some continuous data features. I did a *kde* plot of the features using seaborn kdeplot functionality which gave me a plot as shown below :

[image: Seaborn kdeplot]

How do I interpret this visualization in order to check for things like skew in the data points, etc.?

Comment: it might help to have separate plots for each variable and compute some summary statistics

Comment: Try pandas' `DataFrame.skew()` and `DataFrame.kurtosis()` methods. This superimposed plot is more confusing than informative.

Comment: @Emre Okay but I want to visualize the skewness. Can you tell me how to do that using seaborn or pandas ?

Comment: In pandas in a notebook, `df.variable.hist()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you can use [DataFrame.hist()] method:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(20,4)),columns=list('abcd'))

df.hist(alpha=0.5, figsize=(16, 10))
```

Result:

[image]

Data:

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
    a  b  c  d
0   3  0  2  5
1   8  7  6  6
2   6  4  5  7
3   4  4  0  6
4   5  6  0  2
5   0  0  4  8
6   7  6  7  4
7   7  6  6  2
8   6  5  9  4
9   6  3  6  9
10  7  9  7  6
11  9  3  5  6
12  9  4  7  0
13  2  8  8  8
14  0  8  4  7
15  1  5  2  4
16  2  6  6  4
17  0  3  8  1
18  4  1  0  4
19  4  4  6  8

In [45]: df.skew()
Out[45]:
a   -0.154849
b   -0.239881
c   -0.660912
d   -0.376480
dtype: float64

In [46]: df.describe()
Out[46]:
               a          b          c          d
count  20.000000  20.000000  20.000000  20.000000
mean    4.500000   4.600000   4.900000   5.050000
std     2.964705   2.521487   2.770142   2.502105
min     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
25%     2.000000   3.000000   3.500000   4.000000
50%     4.500000   4.500000   6.000000   5.500000
75%     7.000000   6.000000   7.000000   7.000000
max     9.000000   9.000000   9.000000   9.000000
```